# File cannot be processed when using LinqToExcel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I tried to use a "Form" upload a file to the controller, and some problems occur, 
below is the view code

```
<form action="@Url.Action("uploadRecordFile")" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <label for="file"> Filename : </label>
      <input type="file" name="file" id="file" />
      <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Controller's Code

```
public ActionResult uploadRecordFile(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    if  (file.ContentLength > 0)
    {
        var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
        var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/FileUploads"), fileName);
        file.SaveAs(path);
    }

    var ExcelFileName = new ExcelQueryFactory(@Url.Content("~/FileUpload/" + file.FileName.ToString()));

    foreach (var item in excel) // when the code runs into this, there is some error statements
       {

//   'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' 類型的例外狀況發生於 System.Data.dll，但使用者程式碼未加以處理
//   其他資訊: 外部資料表不是預期的格式。
```

sorry, that is chinese, i think it said that ' the type exception happens in System.Data.dll, but the code cannot be processed ; other's information : the data table is not the expected format

---

I tried to use the same file and test the "uploadRecordFile" method, I found that it is ok, the method can be smoothly run, so i think that is not the problem of the excel's format

```
    var excelFile = new ExcelQueryFactory("D:/Names.xlsx");
    var excel = excelFile.Worksheet<TrainingRecord>();
```

I think there is some code need to convert the file when the controller process the file

Comment: it is not clear what excel variable is in your controller's example

Comment: Where is the connection properties & what `excel` variable belongs to? `(External) data table isn't the expected format` means that you're either using wrong connection properties or not in proper Excel format.